# Correct way to point a subdomain to another subdomain using CNAME record

Tags: subdomain, cname-record

Heyy, I have recently pointed subdomain A to subdomain B using a CNAME record.
What bothers me is the browser's address bar, meaning when I visit subdomain A it then automatically shows the url of subdomain B. How can I show just the subdomain A url on the address bar?

I have also pinged subdomain A and correctly shows the IP of subdomain B, I have also added a 301 permanent redirect but same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

> I have also added a 301 permanent redirect

That's why the browser is redirected to host name B and shows that name.

DNS has no direct connection to HTTP. A browser doesn't care whether it gets a straight A-record name resolution or an indirect one via CNAME. So, if you just set up a CNAME and make your web server respond to that host name you're done.